# Unknown column in Laravel equivalent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am beginner in Laravel. I have problem with my mysql.

I have this code:

1. Model:

```
    class Product extends Model
    {
        use ScopeActiveTrait;
        use Slugable;
    
        public function setNameAttribute($value)
        {
            $this->attributes['name'] = $value;
            $this->attributes['slug'] = $this->makeSlug($value);
        }
    
        protected $fillable = ['delivery_time', 'product_type', 'name', 'title', 'description', 'keywords', 'content', 'vat_id', 'main_category_id', 'enable', 'slug', 'small_description'];
        protected $quarded = ['id'];
        public $timestamps = false;
    
        public function vat()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\VAT', 'vat_id');
        }
    
        public function category()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'main_category_id');
        }
    
        public function selectedCategory()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SelectedProductCategory', 'product_id', 'id');
        }
    
        public function related()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\RelatedProduct');
        }
    
        public function features()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SelectedProductFeature');
        }
    
    
        public function frontImage()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UploadImage', 'file_id', 'id')->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->where('file_type', 'products');
        }
    }
    
    class SelectedProductCategory extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'category_id'];
        protected $quarded = ['id'];
    }
```

2. schema:

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 155);
     $table->string('title', 155);
     $table->string('description', 155)->nullable();
     $table->string('keywords', 155)->nullable();
     $table->longText('content')->nullable();
     $table->string('delivery_time', 155)->nullable();
     $table->string('small_description', 155)->nullable();
     $table->smallInteger('vat_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
     $table->foreign('vat_id')->references('id')->on('vat');
     $table->bigInteger('main_category_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
     //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
     $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
     $table->char('product_type', 1)->default(0);
     $table->string('promo_desc', 3)->nullable();
     $table->string('slug', 160)->nullable();
     $table->engine = "InnoDB";
     $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
     $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
    });
```

```
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->string('category_name', 155);
     $table->string('description', 155)->nullable();
     $table->string('keywords', 155)->nullable();
     $table->longText('content')->nullable();
     $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
     $table->bigInteger('order')->default(0);
     $table->string('slug', 160)->nullable();
     NestedSet::columns($table);
     $table->engine = "InnoDB";
     $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
     $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
    });
```

3. Repository:

```
    public function getProductFromIdCategories($categories)
        {
            return $this->model->select('name', 'slug', 'products.id', 'small_description')
                ->with(['selectedCategory', 'frontImage', 'selectedCategory' => function($q) use ($categories){
                    $q->whereIn('category_id', $categories);
                }])->whereIn('category_id', $categories)->active()->get();
        }
```

In $categories I have array:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => 12
]
```

My product is assigned to this category.

I have error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `name`, `slug`, `products`.`id`, `small_description` from `products` where `category_id` in (12) and `enable` = 1)
```

I don;'t know why. I have this column in selected_product_categories

How can I repair this problem?

Comment: Hi Operloa. Why is row with 'category_id' in the product schema commented out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
    public function getProductFromIdCategories($categories)
    {
        return $this->model->select('name', 'slug', 'products.id', 'small_description')
            ->with(['selectedCategory', 'frontImage', 'selectedCategory' => function($q) use ($categories){
                $q->whereIn('category_id', $categories);
            }])->whereIn('category_id', $categories)->active()->get();
    }
```

on this

```
    public function getProductFromIdCategories($categories)
    {
        return $this->model->select('name', 'slug', 'products.id', 'small_description')
            ->with(['frontImage', 'selectedCategory'])
            ->whereHas('selectedCategory', function ($q) use($categories) {
                $q->whereIn('category_id', $categories);
            })->active()->get();
    }
```

Comment: I have in selected_product_categories category_id: https://ibb.co/mhcBxN9

Comment: and I have relation: selectedCategory in Product

Comment: @operloa `selected_product_categories` is a pivot table and should be treated as such when defining a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between product and categories

Comment: @operloa I changed the answer